# SCHEME: Why does 'set!' modify a local variable of 'let'?

Tags: count, scheme, set, let

I've been searching for a while and I can't find the proper question, so I will post it. I hope that is not posted already.

I understand what *set!* and *let* do, but I don't understand why *set!* can modifies a local variable of *let* and keep the value forever. For example:

```
(define count
  (let ((cont 0))
    (lambda ()
      (set! cont (+ cont 1))
      cont)))
```

If we evaluate *(count)* several times we see that the result is

```
> (count)
1
> (count)
2
> (count)
3
>
```

... and so on. But, as far I understand, *cont* is a local variable, so why it keeps the value? Why it's not set to 0 every time the function is call?

Well, that is :)
Thanks in advance!

PS: Excuse my English *o*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `count` is creating a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) that "stores" the value of `cont`, and it will remember its value even between procedure calls. Notice that the `lambda` is assigned to the `count` name *after* defining `cont` as a variable, and in doing so `lambda` closes over `cont`. It's no longer a *local* variable, its a variable that's defined outside the procedure and is being shared between all of its invocations, "remembering" the value it had in the last invocation.

For comparison, look how a procedure with truly local variables looks:

```
(define count
  (lambda ()
    (let ((cont 0))
      (set! cont (+ cont 1))
      cont)))
```

The above will *always* return `1`, compare it with the procedure in the question.

Comment: Does every procedure that defines a variable behaves the same way? (remembering the value of the variable)

Comment: @ee7 no, only those that define variables _before_ the `lambda`. Look at my edited answer, there's an example of a truly local variable that won't be "remembered" between calls. You have to understand the concept of closures to see why it works like this.

Comment: Oh! now I get it! 
Sorry, I had only saw the first edition of your answer while writing the response to the same :P